# What is a safe and quick way to clear values in a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Every day I have to paste in new values for three columns in a Sharepoint list. To confirm, I want to keep the list items, but want to overwrite the existing values with the new values I'm pasting. Only these three columns are shown in my list view.

In quick edit mode, I tried selecting all of the items and backspacing, but it only clears out the first cell. So there's got to be a better way (I hope).

What is the safest and quickest way to clear those values, please?

Comment: So I'm left wondering there's no way to do this easily? I'll give Power Automate another look; perhaps there's something I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have found a workaround for using Quick Edit.

The **Delete** action doesn’t work but the **Copy and Paste** action works. So I open an empty Excel workbook, copy the empty cells and then paste them in the SharePoint list using Quick Edit.

It works for special columns (Person and Group/Lookup) as well.

[image]

Comment: Great idea! It works for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @rizingfenix Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful in any way? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.

Comment: Doh! Absolutely! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type, ie. text to number. The non conform data will be deleted, then you can change back. Works for simple cases and pretty fast to execute